# Replace a string in a file preceeded by another string

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

I have a bunch of config files looking as follows:

```
reader_0 = newcamd({
name = "Oct 1",
host = "hostname 1",
port = 27020,
user = "UNAME",
pass = "password1",
key  = "0102030405060708091011121314",
})

reader_1 = newcamd({
name = "Oct 2",
host = "hostname 2",
port = 27020,
user = "UNAME",
pass = "password2",
key  = "0102030405060708091011121314",
})
```

How can replace a port number 27020 with another one, for example, 22443, in the section 'reader_1' using **sed**?

Thank you.

Comment: I think there's a formatting error in your post: You didn't put the four spaces before the closing braces `})`. This raises the question: Are the two sections from different files or do they belong to one file?

Comment: Are you having reader_3 also?

Comment: What's fixed and what's variable? Is "reader_1 = newcamd({" fixed? Is the existing port always 27020 or can that vary?

Comment: Will the reader_1 section always have a "port" definition?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, all reader_* sections have a 'port' parameter. 
The existing port number is 27020 in all files. All variables are actually constant and same in all files.

Comment: @P_Yadav No, there are only two readers in each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple similar lines in the same file you would have to type:

`sed -i ':a;N;$!ba; s/27020/22443/2' file`

Where **/2** would mean that it will replace the second match for **27020**. You can test the command with the command sed without the -i parameter in order to see which result gives you.

Otherwise with a simple `sed -i 's/27020/22443/g' file` it would be valid, as long as you know which file modify.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've been looking for!

Comment: I used this command for multiple files  sed -i -- ':a;N;$!ba; s/27020/22443/2' *

Answer (score 6):

Using sed's predecessor ed:

```
ed -s input <<< $'/^reader_1 =\n/^port =\nc\nport = 22443,\n.\nw\nq'
```

This sends `ed` an ANSI-quoted here-string of commands to edit the file. The commands are, in sequence:

1. `/^reader_1 =` -- search for the line beginning with "reader_1 ="
2. `/^port =` -- search forwards from there for the line beginning with "port ="
3. `c` -- change that line
4. `port = 22443,` -- to that text
5. `.` -- end the replacement text
6. `w` -- write the file to disk
7. `q` -- quit `ed`

You could tighten or loosen the regular expressions to match more or less carefully, according to your actual data.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that `reader_0` has `host = hostanme 1`, `reader_1` has `host = hostname 2` and so on.

You can use this command to replace from `file`:

```
sed -i '/host = "hostname 2",/{N;s/port = 27020,/port = 22443,/}' file
```

Comment: This also assumes that `port` always follows `host`. If we assume that the fields and their orders are always the same, then you can also add 2 additional `N`s and match from `/^reader_1\b/` instead of `/host = "hostname 2",/`.

Comment: Yeah, that will be more general.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better done with `awk` in which you can use a state-machine style technique:

```
awk '/^reader_1 = newcamd\({/ { section_found = 1} /})/ { section_found = 0 } section_found && /port = 27020,$/ { sub(/27020,$/, "22443,") } { print }' file1 > file2 && mv file2 file1
```

Explanation:

Set a flag when the section start is found:

```
/^reader_1 = newcamd\({/ {
    section_found = 1
}
```

Clear the flag when the end of a section is found:

```
/})/ {
    section_found = 0
}
```

Substitute the new port number when in the right section and on the right line:

```
section_found && /port = 27020,$/ {
    sub(/27020,$/, "22443,")
}
```

Print all lines:

```
{
    print
}
```

Send output to file2 (a temporary file):

```
> file2
```

If everything was successful, rename file2 to file1:

```
&& mv file2 file1
```

You can make the regular expressions as loose or tight as you need.

This type of code is easier to read and maintain than `sed` or `ed` code, especially if you format it similarly to the way I have in my explanation.